# ASP RegularExpressionValidator with server tags

Tags: asp.net, regex, aspx-user-control

Is there any possibility to use server tags with RegularExpressionValidator
e.g

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ValidationExpression="<%# Common_.getValidationExpression(); %>" ControlToValidate="txtPhone" ErrorMessage="Please enter alphanumeric values" />
```

Actually I want to manage all the regular expressions in single class and I also want to use server tags on ASPX pages not in codebehind :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself.

First define the class with const value

```
public class MyRegex
{
  public const string NameRegex= @"^[a-z0-9]+$";
}
```

and then use it like this (please read till last line)

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="REV_Id" runat="server" ValidationExpression="<%# MyRegex.NameRegex %>" ControlToValidate="txtPhone" ErrorMessage="Please enter alphanumeric values" />
```

Edit here,
Sorry guys above will resolve the server tag error but didn't apply regex to asp.net controls, as far as I noticed, when I just paste that piece of code in CodeBehind in PageLoad, it working fine.

```
REV_Id.ValidationExpression = MyRegex.NameRegex;
```

I wondered why this is not working in aspx page :S ...